# How to import using mercurial with SSH?

Tags: go, mercurial

Is it possible to import a module using mercurial with ssh?

I have found very little on using mercurial with go and the little that I found was with http.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

The text displayed by `go help importpath`, or available [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths), describes how to set import paths so as to imply a particular version control system.  Some sites are known in advance:

> A few common code hosting sites have special syntax:
>
> [list snipped, but GitHub implies using Git protocol, Launchpad implies Bazaar, and so on]
>
> For code hosted on other servers, import paths may either be qualified with the version control type, or the go tool can dynamically fetch the import path over https/http and discover where the code resides from a <meta> tag in the HTML.

So if you don't have access to or control over this sort of `<meta>` tag, you should import with an explicitly-specified VCS:

> ... an import path of the form
>
> ```
> repository.vcs/path
> ```
>
> specifies the given repository, with or without the .vcs suffix, using the named version control system, and then the path inside that repository.

That is, to tell `go get` that it must speak Mercurial protocol to host `example.com` you might use:

```
import "example.com/me.hg/repo"
```

or:

```
import "example.com/me/repo.hg"
```

where the `.hg` is what implies the use of Mercurial.

Once you've chosen a specific VCS, things get a little trickier:

> When a version control system supports multiple protocols, each is tried in turn when downloading. For example, a Git download tries https://, then git+ssh://.

The [source code](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/internal/get/vcs.go) for the Go VCS importer has the details.  Mercurial repository imports try `https` first, then `ssh`.

If you can use the `<meta>` tag, *that* can provide more detail, so that you can avoid the relatively clumsy `.hg` in the import path:

> If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import over https/http and looks for a <meta> tag in the document's HTML <head>.

If you're implementing the `<meta>` response to the request page,read *all* of the rest of this, because this goes on to say:

> When using modules, an additional variant of the go-import meta tag is recognized and is preferred over those listing version control systems. That variant uses "mod" as the vcs in the content value, as in:
>
> ```
> <meta name="go-import" content="example.org mod https://code.org/moduleproxy">
> ```
>
> This tag means to fetch modules with paths beginning with example.org from the module proxy available at the URL https://code.org/moduleproxy. See 'go help goproxy' for details about the proxy protocol.